# How to remove this double quote before curly braces from this json string

Tags: java, android

I found no particular solution for my json string. I want to remove the double quotes from both end of the jsonObject. For better understanding I am sharing you the screenshot.

[image]
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is a server side mistake, fix it on the server

Comment: it isn't correct JSON ask server dev to fix it.

Comment: can i remove it from that postion, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON string format is the same you can use the following code to get your desired result:

```
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("(\"\\{\")","\\{\"").replaceAll("(\"\\}\")","\"\\}");
```

It simply removes all the leading and trailing double quotes from every array element.

You can convert your string into JSON using the following code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(jsonString);
```